# Count-based (percentage) data - Generalized linear model

Tags: count, percentage, glm, proportions

I am new to statistical analysis and R. I have stomach content data of 8 small fish species. The food items were classified into 5 categories. I spread the stomach content on a slide and viewed   under a microscope with an ocular grid with 81 intersection points. Four replicates were carried out for each sample. The items under each intersection point were recorded. As there was nothing under some of the intersection points, the total counts were different for each sample. I would like to see if there are differences among species and site.The data can be simulated as follows.

```
Species <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
Site <- c("Site 1", "Site 2", "Site 3", "Site 4")
df <- expand.grid(Species = species, Site = site)
df$Item1 <- round(runif(nrow(df), min = 50, max = 350), 0)
df$Item2 <- round(runif(nrow(df), min = 10, max = 250), 0)
df$Item3 <- round(runif(nrow(df), min = 0, max = 50), 0)
df$Item4 <- round(runif(nrow(df), min = 0, max = 30), 0)
df$Item5 <- round(runif(nrow(df), min = 0, max = 75), 0)
df$Total<- rowSums(df[, c("Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5")])
```

I tried to use generalized linear model with binomial distribution in glmmTMB but it does not work.

```
Warning messages:
1: In .checkRankX(TMBStruc, control$rank_check) :
  fixed effects in conditional model are rank deficient
2: In fitTMB(TMBStruc) :
  Model convergence problem; non-positive-definite Hessian matrix. See vignette('troubleshooting')

> glmmTMB:::Anova.glmmTMB(mod1)
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 't': NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

Should I convert the data into percentage and try again? If so, what distribution can I use?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!